# Why do distribution functions have Leibniz rule?

Tags: probability, analysis

Suppose I have two distribution functions $f, g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,1]$, I.e. Non-decreasing, right continuous with $\underset{t\rightarrow \infty}{\lim} = 1, \underset{t\rightarrow - \infty}{\lim}= 0$.  Why does the measure given by the product of the distribution functions obey the Leibniz rule: $d(f\cdot g)=g df + f dg$?  By $df$ I mean the Borel measure given by assigning the measure $f(b)-f(a)$ to the interval $(a,b]$.

Comment: How is $d$ defined? Is it the weak derivative?

Comment: @Ian I added a sentence to clarify

Comment: I guess you want a half-open interval instead of $[a,b]$

Comment: @user8268 I'm not sure. Does it matter?

Comment: yes, if $f$ is not continuous

Comment: Oh! Yes, thanks

Comment: Informally, the measure is the derivative of the distribution function. (Informally, because I don't specify in which sense exactly it is the derivative.)

Comment: @DanielFischer so are you saying the Leibniz formula follows after making precise the sense in which df is a derivative of f?

Comment: Well, what is the left side? That part is easy: it is the measure obtained by extending $(a,b] \mapsto f(b) g(b) - f(a) g(a)$. What is the right side, say when restricted to intervals of the form $(a,b]$? (Here the meaning is a little bit more subtle because you have the product of a function and a measure.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ have CDF  $F_X$. Then the integral  $\int h(x) d F_X(x)$ is to be understood as $E [ h(X)]$.

Now suppose that $X$ and and $Y$ are independent with CDF $F$ and $G$ respectively. Then $Z= \max (X,Y)$ has CDF $FG$. Thus,

$$ \int h(z) d FG (z) = E [ h(Z) ] .$$

Now

\begin{align} 
E [ h(Z) ] &=  E [ h(X), Y\le X]+ E [ h(Y) ,X < Y]  
\end{align}

Conditioning on $X$, then taking expectation, we have

$$E [ h(X) ,Y \le X] = E [ h(X)G(X)] .$$

Similarly,

$$E [ h(Y),X<Y] = E[h(Y) F(X-)],$$

where $F(x-)$ is the limit from the left of $F$ at $x$.

Rewriting the above expectations as integrals we obtain

$$ \int h(z) d FG(z) = \int h(z)G(z) d F(z) + \int h(z) F(z-) d G(z).$$

Thus,

$$ d FG (z) = G(z) d F(z)+ F(z-) d G(z).$$

If $F$ is continuous, then $F(z-)=F(z)$.

Note. The same argument with roles of $X$ and $Y$ interchanged gives

$$ d FG (z) =   F(z) d G(z)+ G(z-) d F(z).$$

Therefore whenever $F$ or $G$ are continuous, we have

$$ d FG (z) =  F(z) d G(z) + G(z) d F(z).$$

Finally, exercise: what is the meaning of the left limit ? When does it actually matter ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'll Have to read this tomorrow.

Comment: I see. So it's true so long as $F$, $G$ Don't have a common point of discontinuity.

Comment: correct. good example to keep in mind is when both are CDF of  Bernoulli $p$